# Dart: non-nullable local variable initialized in if block fails with "must be assigned before it can be used"

Tags: dart

I'm using Dart 2.15.1 with default setting *null safety* enabled. I don't understand, why this does not work:

```dart
main() {
  int test;
  if (1 > 0) { test = 42; }
  print(test); // <- The non-nullable local variable 'test' must be assigned before it can be used.
}
```

while this works without any error:

```dart
main() {
  int test;
  if (true) { test = 42; }
  print(test); // <- no error here
}
```

It's not a big thing, I can certainly implement a workaround, but I'm curious why dart behaves like this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think it's because `1 > 0` invokes `int.operator >`, and although `1` and `0` are `int` literals, Dart doesn't have a notion of functions that can be evaluated at compilation-time, so `operator >` won't be evaluated until runtime.  I think there are some cases where constants can be folded, though, so there probably can be some exceptions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart infers some control flow at compile time, but only really for very simple boolean expressions, basically only literals.

The expression `0 < 1` is guaranteed to be `true`, but the language specification treats it as a run-time evaluated expression, the meaning of which cannot be known until after it has been evaluated, which means it has to be typed first, and flow analysis happens *during* the type analysis step.
So, the `if` is treated in the flow analysis as a branch that can go either way.